# Python Setting and Recalling Cookies

Tags: python, cookies

Is there any way that I could set a cookie and later recall a variable from that cookie using python? Like:

```
    > setcookie("prefence","data")
    ...
    > recallcookie("preference")
    data
```

I would prefer not to use libraries that aren't built in, but if necessary, I am fine with using an external library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself, using SimpleCookies and the HTTP_COOKIE environmental variable.
In the content header, define cookies as normal (SimpleCookies makes this simple). For example:

```
from http import cookies
cookie = cookies.SimpleCookie()
cookie["varname"] = 'value'
print(cookie.output())
```

Then normal cookie variables can be assigned like so:

```
cookie["varname"] = 'value'
cookie["varname"]["expires"] = "formatted date"
cookie["varname"]["othercookieproperty"] =  "othercookieproperty"
```

To recall them, one can make a Simple Cookie out of the HTTP_COOKIE environmental variable, like so:

```
readcookie = cookies.SimpleCookie(os.environ["HTTP_COOKIE"])
print(readcookie["varname"].value)
```

This would print 'value', the value assigned earlier. These can also be called between sessions, until the cookie expires.